# MySQL, Java, and TimeZone

Tags: java, mysql, sql, timezone

I have a datetime type field `some_field` in a MySQL database.  I can query the data using `recordSet.getTimestamp("somefield")`, which returns a `java.sql.Timestamp` object.  However, the returned values stores a UTC time.  Now if know the time zone is "America/Chicago", how can I convert the time.  I have to take care of DST.

Comment: Maybe I should use `getString()` instead of `getTimestamp()`.  Java's datetime API stinks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to ignore the sub-millisecond precision of `Timestamp` - which is probably reasonable, as if you're converting to a particular time zone, that suggests it's meant to be a "human" date. Anyway:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(zone); // Also locale?
calendar.setTime(timestamp);
```

Now you can ask the calendar for whatever values you want - date, hour of day etc.

Alternatively, you might want to consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which is a much better date/time API:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago");
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp.getTime(), zone);
```

Comment: Problem... Now in the database I have a time '2012-07-31 16:00:00' and the timezone is `Timezone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern")`. But the `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` is 17. I think that's because my server's tz is "US/Central"?  What shall I do?

Comment: @seanhawk: You need to determine for sure the exact value returned to the Java code. If you print out `timestamp.getTime()` what does it show? (I won't be able to help until tomorrow, but I'll have a look then.)

Comment: When the time is "2012-07-31 20:22:03" and timezone is "US/Pacific", `timestamp.getTime()` is 1343784123000, which is "Wed, 01 Aug 2012 01:22:03 GMT" (see www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).  This means `resultSet.getTimestamp()` treats the result as if it is in the app server's timezone, which is "US/Central" in my case. BTW, `resultSEt.getTimestamp(key, cal)` gets exactly same `Timestamp`.

Comment: @seanhawk: It sounds like you need to get what's stored in the database straight. Is it *meant* to store the data as a US/Central time? If you change the time zone, does that change the meaning of the data that's already stored? That would be pretty nasty.

Comment: I have two columns in the DB. One is of type `datetime` (in the case of MySQL, it is basically a string and has no timezone info). The other is a `varchar` that stores the timezone. The data are from all over the country, so there are different timezones. I don't want to change the structure of the DB as it isn't my design. I don't know about the other DBMS, but I feel the date/time types in MySQL is pretty nasty.

Comment: @seanhawk: When you say "stores the timezone" - stores which timezone? The timezone you want to convert *to*, or the timezone of the date stored in the database? Sorry, it's still very unclear what the value in the database *really* represents, and it's hugely important that you're rock solid when understanding that. In your sample value, would the database store "US/Central" or "US/Pacific"? It's really unfortunate if the time zone of the server affects what data is stored :(

Comment: The second column stores the timezones of records. So if a record is from NYC, that column will be "US/Eastern". If it is from LA, then "US/Pacific". I need to convert the `datetime` column to UTC times in my application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14727/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-sean-hawk)